# Custom String - Missing : after property list

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-formatting

I have been working on getting $.ajax data compiled by using an php class I wrote. The data come out like this:

```
{ 
0: [ 
    { Status : "example status 2"
    , Contact ID Number : "1"
    , Date Entered : "2011-06-15"
    , Date Assigned : "2011-06-15"
    , Date Last Modified : "2011-06-15"
    , Deceased Date : ""
    , Linked To Registrant 1 : "Leona Brown"
    , Relationship 1 : "Father"
    , Authorization 1 : "1"
    , Linked To Registrant 2 : "Henry Sale"
    , Relationship 2 : "Husband"
    , Authorization 2 : "1"
    , Location : "Hamilton Harron Funeral Home"
    , Sales Manager : "Dan Thompson"
    , Counselor : "Mike Brown"
    , Registration Number : "1"
    , Registration Date : "2001-05-11"
    , Program 1 Number : "2"
    , Program 1 Date : "2003-11-05"
    , Program 1 Name : "Non Registrant Test Program - Advantage"
    , Program 2 Number : "--"
    , Program 2 Date : "--"
    , Program 2 Name : "--"
    , First Name : "Onelia"
    , Last Name : "Garcy"
    , Address Location 1 : "home"
    , Address 1 : ""
    , City 1 : "Houston"
    , State/Province 1 : "Texas"
    , Zip/Postal Code 1 : "77019"
    , Home Phone : "--"
    , Work Phone : "--"
    , Mobile Phone : "--"
    , Pager : "--"
    , Other Phone : "--"
    , Email : ""
    , Sales Type : "Pre-Need"
    , Note 1 : "This is Note 3. This is Note 3. This is Note 3. This is Note 3. This is Note 3. This is Note 3. This is Note 3. This is Note 3. This is Note 3. This is Note 3. This is Note 3. This is Note 3. This is Note 3. This is Note 3. This is Note 3. " 
    } 
]
, 1: [ 
    { Status : ""
    , Contact ID Number : "2"
    , Date Entered : "2011-07-02"
    , Date Assigned : "2011-07-02"
    , Date Last Modified : "2011-07-02"
    , Deceased Date : ""
    , Linked To Registrant 1 : "--"
    , Relationship 1 : "--"
    , Authorization 1 : "--"
    , Linked To Registrant 2 : "--"
    , Relationship 2 : "--"
    , Authorization 2 : "--"
    , Location : "Floral Haven Funeral Home "
    , Sales Manager : "Jayson Gordon"
    , Counselor : "Henry Murdoc"
    , Registration Number : "3"
    , Registration Date : "2003-12-02"
    , Program 1 Number : "4"
    , Program 1 Date : "2004-03-05"
    , Program 1 Name : "Non Registrant Test Program - Advantage"
    , Program 2 Number : "--"
    , Program 2 Date : "--"
    , Program 2 Name : "--"
    , First Name : "Leo"
    , Last Name : "Brown"
    , Address Location 1 : "home"
    , Address 1 : "5330 Ridge Rd "
    , City 1 : "Burlington"
    , State/Province 1 : "Ontario"
    , Zip/Postal Code 1 : "LVL7N9"
    , Home Phone : "9053919735"
    , Work Phone : "--"
    , Mobile Phone : "9057303737"
    , Pager : "--"
    , Other Phone : "--"
    , Email : "hmind@dont.com"
    , Sales Type : "PN to AN"
    , Note 1 : "This is Note 5. This is Note 5. This is Note 5. This is Note 5. This is Note 5. This is Note 5. This is Note 5. This is Note 5. This is Note 5. This is Note 5. This is Note 5. This is Note 5. This is Note 5. " 
    } 
]
, 2: [ 
    { Status : "example1 status"
    , Contact ID Number : "3"
    , Date Entered : "2011-09-05"
    , Date Assigned : "2011-09-05"
    , Date Last Modified : "2011-09-05"
    , Deceased Date : ""
    , Linked To Registrant 1 : "Onelia Gary"
    , Relationship 1 : "Wife"
    , Authorization 1 : "1"
    , Linked To Registrant 2 : "--"
    , Relationship 2 : "--"
    , Authorization 2 : "--"
    , Location : "First Memorial Funeral Services"
    , Sales Manager : "Dan Thompson", Counselor : "Steve Brown"
    , Registration Number : "5"
    , Registration Date : "2010-11-11"
    , Program 1 Number : "7"
    , Program 1 Date : "2011-08-19"
    , Program 1 Name : "Non Registrant Test Program - Dignity"
    , Program 2 Number : "6"
    , Program 2 Date : "2011-07-03"
    , Program 2 Name : "Non Registrant Test Program - Advantage"
    , First Name : "Henry"
    , Last Name : "Murdoc"
    , Address Location 1 : "company"
    , Address 1 : "9055 Harvy Rd. 4"
    , City 1 : "Burlington"
    , State/Province 1 : "Ontario"
    , Zip/Postal Code 1 : "L7L5Z7"
    , Home Phone : "9055679602"
    , Work Phone : "9057455209"
    , Mobile Phone : "--"
    , Pager : "--"
    , Other Phone : "--"
    , Email : "pewter@live.com"
    , Sales Type : "At-Need"
    , Note 1 : "This is Note 6. This is Note 6. This is Note 6. This is Note 6. This is Note 6. This is Note 6. This is Note 6. This is Note 6. This is Note 6. This is Note 6. This is Note 6. This is Note 6. This is Note 6. This is Note 6. "
    } 
   ] 
}
```

Firebug reports this error:

> missing : after property id
>   .../view_contacts_search_1.php#
>   Line 188

It fails when instantiating a variable:

```
<script type='text/javascript' >
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
                var data = <?php echo($data)?>;
```

Can you spot what/where the missing element is? I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours and it has me stumped. Being new to javascipt and jquery does not help either :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property names are numeric - that is not valid JavaScript. Try renaming the top level properties or making them strings.

These are all valid replacements:

```
{ 
    _0: [ ...

{ 
    number0: [ ...

{ 
    '0': [ ...
```

But honestly it is always best to make the property names quoted strings to avoid issues like this.

Comment: Can I convert the numeric property names to strings and it will work?

Comment: Yea, and then the _vast majority_ of the other ones are multi-word strings without enclosing quotes.

Comment: Ok trying to fix this now. Will see if that also is part of the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, using a numeric literal for a property name in an object literal (e.g., `{0: "foo"}`) is perfectly valid, see [Section 11.1.5 of the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.5). It quite clearly says that the *PropertyName* part (the left-hand side) of a property initializer must be either an *IdentifierName*, a *StringLiteral*, or a *NumericLiteral*. The problem is the *other* identifiers that Tomalak pointed out, which *are* invalid. Agreed that it's frequently best to use string literals for the property names so you don't have to worry about the rules for identifier names, though.

Comment: Yes using NumericLiterals it did post the data and rid the error after escaping the double words.

Comment: The data posts as 0[0][Address 1] 
0[0][Address Location 1] home
0[0][Authorization 1] 1
0[0][Authorization 2] 1
0[0][City 1] Houston

Comment: The inner zero 1[0][Property Name] is always zero can I format the string so I just get 1[Property name]?

Answer (score 0):

This will work better:

```
{ 
"0": [ 
    { "Status" : "example status 2"
    , "Contact ID Number" : "1"
    , "Date Entered" : "2011-06-15"
    , ...
```

Use PHP's built-in json conversion functions, it will save you pain.

Comment: PHP json_encode does not encode the data properly. I tried using it but instead it gives [Object object, Object object, Object object] as a string. I know it is a string as when json_decode is run the resulting variable is type string. bummer :(

Comment: There has to be a reason why json_encode doesn't work, writing your own json serializer is not the solution to that problem.

Comment: Yes I am sure you are right; although I now have my json_encode working and php does not?!